# How can this integral be solved?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, maple

In the maple:
[image: maple]

In the WolframAlpha:
[image: WolframAlpha]

What it is wrong? Could you explain me?

Comment: The type in which you are trying to ask your question is wrong. Please read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) carefully

Answer (score 1):

In WolframAlpha testing the two results to see if they are the same or not

```
Simplify[-1/2 x(cos(log(34 x))-sin(log(34 x)))==
  (x tan(log(34 x)/2)-x/2+x tan(log(34 x)/2)^2/2)/(1+tan(log(34 x)/2)^2)]
```

(all done on a single line) returns

```
True
```

[Link to WolframAlpha result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Simplify%5B-1%2F2%20x%28cos%28log%2834%20x%29%29-sin%28log%2834%20x%29%29%29%3D%3D%28x%20tan%28log%2834%20x%29%2F2%29-x%2F2%2Bx%20tan%28log%2834%20x%29%2F2%29%5E2%2F2%29%2F%281%2Btan%28log%2834%20x%29%2F2%29%5E2%29%5D)

so the result from WolframAlpha and from Maple are equivalent, they are just expressed in different forms.

Ah, a simpler way to get the same result, doesn't even need the `Simplify`

```
-1/2 x(cos(log(34 x))-sin(log(34 x)))==
  (x tan(log(34 x)/2)-x/2+x tan(log(34 x)/2)^2/2)/(1+tan(log(34 x)/2)^2)
```

returns

```
True
```

[Another link to WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-1%2F2%20x%28cos%28log%2834%20x%29%29-sin%28log%2834%20x%29%29%29%3D%3D%28x%20tan%28log%2834%20x%29%2F2%29-x%2F2%2Bx%20tan%28log%2834%20x%29%2F2%29%5E2%2F2%29%2F%281%2Btan%28log%2834%20x%29%2F2%29%5E2%29)

Answer (score 1):

They are different representations of the same thing.

It is quite straightforward to demonstrate this in Maple itself.

```
restart;

A1 := int(sin(ln(34*x)),x):

lprint(A1);

   (x*tan(1/2*ln(34*x))-1/2*x+1/2*x*tan(1/2*ln(34*x))^2)
   /(1+tan(1/2*ln(34*x))^2)

A2 := combine(combine(simplify(A1))):

lprint(A2);

   1/2*x*sin(ln(34*x))-1/2*x*cos(ln(34*x))

simplify(A1 - A2);

                0
```